# how to disable device dark mode support in react native app

Tags: react-native, darkmode

I have implemented dark mode support in my application by giving such an option and working so well but there is a situation like many ANDROID & iOS device also having in-build dark mode functionality If device's dark mode is enabled then App is not the same look what I was given by applying app dark mode like

> Background, text color is different than my version of dark mode

so I want to disable that device dark mode support for my app.

Please suggest me how can I achieve this?
Thanks